# Why does my recursive query stop after one step?

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I would like to get a list of employees in an organization that ultimately report to a given person (a flattened sub-tree of the org chart). I created a sample organization (in SQLite, [view on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bHqxsj1YstjMg78pZDpNe8/0)) with `john` as the boss, who has two reports (`luc` and `bob`) and `bob` has one report (`steve`).

In order to seed the recursive query, I want to use the `nickname` (and get a list of `nickname`) but the relationship between the people is based on their `login`.

```sql
create table users (
  login text,
  nickname text,
  manager text
  );
  
 insert into users values ('john', 'j',  NULL), ('luc', 'l', 'john'), ('bob', 'b', 'john'), ('steve', 's', 'bob');
```

I created a recursive query

```sql
WITH orgtree AS (
select login  from users where users.nickname='j'

UNION all
    
SELECT users.nickname FROM users, orgtree
WHERE users.manager=orgtree.login
)

SELECT users.nickname FROM users
WHERE users.nickname IN orgtree ;
```

What I get as a result is just the "first line" of `j` (of `john`):

| nickname |
| --- |
| l |
| b |

What am I missing in my query to go deeper? (in either the anchor or the recursive member?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is that the recursive member of the CTE returns the user's nickname, while you need their login to be able to look up the next hierarchical level. A direct fix is:

```
with orgtree as (
    select login  from users where users.nickname='j'
    union all
    select users.login 
    from users, orgtree
    where users.manager=orgtree.login
)
select nickname from users where login in orgtree;
```

But we can further improve the query, by keeping track of both the nickname *and* the login in the recursive, so there is no need for `in` in the outer query:

```
with orgtree as (
    select nickname, login from users where nickname = 'j'
    union all
    select u.nickname, u.login 
    from users u
    inner join orgtree o on u.manager = o.login
)
select nickname from orgtree
```

Note that I used standard, explicit joins rather than implicit, old-school joins.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MIr9PBys)**

| nickname |
| --- |
| j |
| b |
| l |
| s |

Comment: Thank you. Is there a reason to prefer the second version vs. the first one? (performance maybe?)